# When using the accelerometer why does the onSensorChanged() method get called regularly when no sensor values are being changed?

Tags: android, android-sensors

**This is how the accelerometer part in the app works:**
Once a button in the application is clicked the objective is to read the accelerometer values and play a audio clip.

I have isolated the code in question from the application.

**AlarmActivity.java**

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    ...
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private AudioPlayer mPlayer = new AudioPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mPlayer.stop();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSensor() called");

        class StartGuardingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
                mPlayer.play(AlarmActivity.this);
                return null;
            }
        }

        if(mCurrentXVal != mOldXVal || mCurrentYVal != mOldYVal || mCurrentZVal != mOldZVal) {
            mOldXVal = mCurrentXVal;
            mOldYVal = mCurrentYVal;
            mOldZVal = mCurrentZVal;

            mXValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mXValue.setText("x:" + mCurrentXVal);
            mYValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            mYValue.setText("y:" + mCurrentYVal);
            mZValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            mZValue.setText("z:" + mCurrentZVal);

            new StartGuardingTask().execute();
        }
    }
}
```

**AudioPlayer.java**

```
public class AudioPlayer {
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    public void stop() {
        if(mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    public void play(Context c) {
        if(mPlayer == null) {
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.police_siren);

            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stop();
                }
            });
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public MediaPlayer getPlayer() {
        return mPlayer;
    }
}
```

Even when the device is stationary I can see(using logcat) the method being called regularly.

I've read another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528442/android-accelerometer-onsensorchanged-runs-always) where the OP is facing a similar situation.
But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804142/android-alternative-to-onsensorchanged-no-accelerometer-data-when-phone-is-lyi) post suggests the method to be working as expected.
Only if the method worked as advertised I could get rid of the conditional in the onSensorChanged() method.

So if my device is stationary, no sensor values are changed then why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer detects even the smallest variation in value. For example you put your phone lying on the table, and play music. The vibration from the music is enough to cause many repetitive change of the accelerometer, but in very small values. That's why you have to put a conditional in the onSensorChanged() method to be notified of only large enough change in the values.

Answer (score 0):

How do you say that the sensor value didn't changed ? I suppose it should.

You get that fired all the time, because of acceleration due to gravity. Depending on the orientation of your android phone, you will see that some value is reported on the x / y / z axis. For example when you stand still at a place in earth an acceleration 9.8 m/s2 is acting downwards. The same hold true for an Accelerometer in android.